# How to insert an image with url in Export Kartik?

Tags: kartik-v

I am trying to insert logos on the excel and pdf exports through ExportMenu via Kartik Export Menu by using
contentBefore
value:        string, the value of the merged row
styleOptions: array, array of configuration options to set the style. See styleOptions on the
various settings to configure.
How to insert the img tags in the  value with a url? I am unable to insert the image.